# jQuery Hide & Show Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hide

I've created a link, which when clicked on pops open and shows a "Contact Form". It opens, validates, submits & emails fine. I'm running into problems when I try to close the form.

HTML

```
<div id="blanket"><div id="myForm">
    <p style="text-align:right; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><a href="#" id="close" onClick="onClickClose();">Close</a></p>
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="_sendmail.php" onSubmit="return CheckAll(this);">
    <input name="fieldnm_1" type="radio" value="M." /> M. 
    <input name="fieldnm_1" type="radio" value="Mme" /> Mme. 
</td></tr><tr><td width="400">
    <input name="fieldnm_2" type="text" id="left_form" placeholder="Pr&eacute;nom *" tabindex="1"/><input name="fieldnm_4" type="text" id="right_form" placeholder="Courriel *" tabindex="3"/>
</td></tr><tr><td width="400">
    <input name="fieldnm_3" type="text" id="left_form" placeholder="Nom *" tabindex="2"/>
    <input name="fieldnm_5" type="text" id="right_form" placeholder="T&eacute;l&eacute;phone *" tabindex="4"/>
</td></tr><tr><td width="400">
    <select name="fieldnm_7" id="left_list" >
    <option value="">Nombre de chambres *</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
    <select name="fieldnm_8" id="right_list">
    <option value="">Nombre de pieds carr&eacute;s</option>
    <option value="600-800">600-800</option>
    <option value="800-1000">800-1000</option>
    <option value="1000-1250">1000-1250</option>
    <option value="Plus de 1250">Plus de 1250</option>
    </select>
</td></tr><tr><td>
    <textarea name="fieldnm_9" id="comment" placeholder="Commentaire*" tabindex="5"></textarea>
</td></tr><tr><td>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Soumettre" tabindex="6">
<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset">
</td></tr></table></form></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onClickRegister = function(){
    b = $("#blanket");
    b.css("display","block");
    b.css("position","fixed");
    b.css("width", window.innerWidth);
    b.css("height", window.innerHeight);
    b.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)");
    f=$("#myForm");
    f.css("position", "fixed");
    f.css("top", "33%");
    f.css("left", "33%");
}
window.onResize(function(){
    if($("#blanket").length>0){
        b.css("width", window.innerWidth);
        b.css("height", window.innerHeight);
    }
});
onClickClose = function(){
    $("#blanket").css("display","none");
}
</script>
```

I've tried even just adding an alert to the onClickClose and nothing happens.

Comment: use a browser console to find then fix the errors that are being thrown

Comment: When I click on the close button the console says : onClickClose is not defined. So my guess is that it's not finding the function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
function onClickClose(){
    $("#blanket").hide();
}
```

*if you don't want JQuery to save in its cache the value of the display property to be restored later (as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)) you could use just:

```
function onClickClose(){
    $("#blanket").css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: surely `.hide()` would be better

Comment: as the first comment suggest you should do $("#blanket").hide(); and since you are using jquery you should use the other answer's way to write the click handler and remove the onclick from the html

Comment: i prefer functions written this way. maybe you needed a var? var myfunc = function () {}

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#close").click(function() {
 $("#blanket").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your problem isn't with `onClickClose`, it's the `window.onResize()` directly before that. It should be `window.onresize`, no camel-case, and it isn't a function but an event handler. What you should have there is

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if ($("#blanket").length > 0) {
        b.css("width", window.innerWidth);
        b.css("height", window.innerHeight);
    }
};
```

The way you had it was causing an error, and subsequently the `onClickClose` function wasn't getting parsed. Read all about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onresize).

The reason PbxMan's answer works is because of hoisting. By changing it from a function expression to a function declaration, that function gets hoisted to the top of the
scope, and so *does* get parsed before the error. So while it works, it's actually side-stepping the actual issue.

[Angus Croll](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) has a good post on function declarations vs. function expressions and hoisting.

Comment: Exactly, there's no difference between `myFunction = function() { }` and `function myFunction() { }` in this case, they should both work. But due to the error in `onResize` setting the function as a variable was ignored, while the other way of writing it is less brittle I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname Should make no difference in this case.

Comment: In this case it actually does make a difference due to hoisting, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: What I meant was "it should make no difference with your code, if you fix the errors which break your code". Fix the error with onresize and both ways of declaring the function will work fine.

Comment: Yeah, I understood ;) It was just a somewhat interesting, real-life case of not-immediately-evident consequences of the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#close').click(
function(abc){
    $("#blanket").css("display","none");
abc.preventDefault(); // this will cancel the default action for href
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  
** Just Add ) after }**